# why android mycustom adapter not working

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

mycustom adapter which extends from baseadapter but when i run my main java file it shows main activity no 
list view item

```
  public class MyCustomadapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mycontext;
    String[] mystringlist;

    public MyCustomadapter(Context context,String[] strText) {

        this.mycontext=context;
        this.mystringlist = strText;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mystringlist.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mycontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_row, parent,false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowtxt);
        tv.setText(mystringlist[position]);
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

mycustom adapter which extends from baseadapter but when i run my main java file it shows main activity no 
list view item

Comment: thaks a lot Dhaval Condaliya; just this.mycontext = context has solved my problem

Comment: Actually extending `ArrayAdapter` is much better for this basic simple job, and already most of this methods have been overrided by itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**problem:**

```
return 0;
```

You are return 0 means there would be no list items to be displayed in your `ListView` thus giving you 0 result. 
You need to return the `number of item in your array` or the **length** of it.

**sample:**

```
 @Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mystringlist.length;
}
```

Comment: i tried this. but now shows Application stopped unexpectedly

Comment: @raton try `mystringlist.length - 1`

Comment: public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  String[] name ={"raton","kumar","swarnokar"};
  
  lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomadapter(name));
 }

Comment: @raton post it in your post not here. and also post the error

Comment: many many Thanks the getCount method along with Context has solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public int getCount() 
 {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mystringlist.length();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

My idea is extending `ArrayAdapter`, Have a look at the following codes

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // your codes for generating rows
        String thisItem = getItem(position);
    }
}
```

You're done, also you're no longer need to override other methods!

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addendum your `getItem()` method is incorrect.  It should read as follows:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return mystringlist[position];
}
```